# Resize Background Image without affecting the proportion

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, background-image

I am trying to make a slider with background images, when I am trying to make it fit to the mobile screen, the proportion is affected and look as pixels, how can I resize the background-image to fit the mobile screen without affecting the proportion.

and when I increase the `height` to :

```
background-size: 100vw 55vh !important;
height: 55vh !important;
```

Comment: Since you want fixed height than go `background-size: auto 55vh !important;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the object-fit property to maintain the aspect ratio of the image:

```
img {
height: 55vh
object-fit: contain;
}
```

contain - The replaced content is scaled to maintain its aspect ratio while fitting within the element's content box.

Comment: it's a background image not image

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fixing both height and width of the image, just define the one which you need (for example width)  and set the other one to `auto`.  For height that would be:

```
background-size: auto 55vh;
height: 55vh;
```

that way the original image proportion will be kept, avoiding a distorted image.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying (?)

Comment: yes, it's look good , but the whole image not appear, just the center portion appeared

Comment: You can use `background-size: contain` to make sure the whole image appears, but there might be space at two of the sides then.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this CSS:

```
{
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

if it didn't work please share your code. I know I can help you.

Comment: it's not got the height of 55vh, it's get auto height which is look small